# Why does setText in the TextField doesn't work?

Tags: gwt, gxt

Why does this method doesn't save the new selected categories. is there something wrong with my codes?

```
catCon = new TextField();
rowEditing.addEditor(catConfig, catCon);
```

this is the code for setting the catCon:

```
TextButton save = new TextButton("Save");
save.addSelectHandler(new SelectEvent.SelectHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {

                selectedItems = new LinkedList<Short>();
                for (int i = 0; i < toCat.size(); i++) {
                    selectedItems.add(toCat.get(i).getIDCategory());
                }
                Collections.sort(selectedItems);
                newSelectedItems = selectedItems.toString().replace(",", "-").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "");

                msg = new MessageBox("SELECTED ITEMSSSSSSSSS: " + selectedItems.size() + " " + newSelectedItems);;
                msg.show();
                catCon.setText(newSelectedItems);
                hide();
            }
});
```

and this is where the saving of the commited changes:

```
rowEditing.getSaveButton().addSelectHandler(new SelectEvent.SelectHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
                    store.commitChanges();

                    service.saveUserRights(store.get(index), new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                            msg = new MessageBox("Error", caught.getMessage());
                            msg.show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                            if (result) {
                                msg = new MessageBox("Information", "Changes saved.");
                                msg.show();
                                service.getURListGrid(new AsyncCallback<List<UserRights>>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                                        MessageBox msg = new MessageBox("Error", caught.getMessage());
                                        msg.show();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(List<UserRights> result) {
                                        store = new ListStore<UserRights>(properties.idRight());
                                        store.addAll(result);
                                        grid.reconfigure(store, cm);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                msg = new MessageBox("Error", "Failed to save changes.");
                                msg.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

When I am going to set the catCon there will no be changes of the data but when I manually type the categories there will be a change. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What happens when you enable auto commit? store.setAutoCommit(true)

Comment: @udeleng i'll try that line of code. thank you

Comment: @udeleng i'm sorry but it doesn't work. it doesn't save the new selected categories

Comment: auto commit only updates the store; it won't fire your event handler, which is attached to a button. I couldn't tell from your 2nd snippet, what the save button is trying to do. The 3rd snippet seems to be making 2 RPC calls on each row update.  But what if the update fails? now you have a client that permitted the change but the back end didn't, the grid is in an inconsistent state. You should override the onCompleteEditing in your GridRowEditing to delay the editing from being completed until the RPC is successful. Take a look at the GXT demo on Row Editing Grid.

Comment: @udeleng okay thank you. so are you trying to say that store.commitChanges() doesn't really works even if i will manually input the categories?

Comment: @udeleng but according to this link sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:roweditablegrid i also saw that in order to save the changes this line of code is the answer "store.commitChanges();" and why does it doesn't work when i am going to set the catCon :(

Comment: when you use an editor in a grid, the grid store doesn't necessarily update when you're done editing. If auto commit is not enabled, you might see a little green arrow in the cell. Using setText on the editor's field might update the text in the text field, but it won't complete the editing or commit because those are usually tied the user initiated events like pressing some key or clicking the save/cancel button in the editor.

Comment: @udeleng ok thanks but can you give me a hint or a little line of codes on where could I actually put the auto commit?

Answer (score 0):

In order for me to save the current categories is to get the index of the store and set the category to the newSelectedItem

```
store.get(index).setCategories(newSelectedItems);
```

I hope this will help to the people who has the same problem as mine.